# Where would you store the bot token for a discord.py bot?

Tags: discord, discord.py

Where do you usually store the bot token/API key for a discord bot or any program that integrates a bot token? I just have mine stored in the main.py file. Is there an agreed upon way to store keys and tokens such as a discord bot token? My bot works fine but I would like to know if there is a specific way to store these values or if it's something preferential like using single quotes or double quotes.

I've seen one example of a discord token being stored in a separate JSON file. Is this the preferred way to store keys and tokens in?

I'll show you a quick example of what I'm talking about.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-', case_insensitive=True)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"{bot.user.name} is online and ready to go! Bot id: {bot.user.id}")


bot.run('botToken')
# I have mine placed right here in the botToken value.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*This quick overview should only be considered if you are working on a hobby project. If you are doing anyhting commercial, be more serious about it.*

**Leaving the token in your file (hardcoding it)**

Pro

- Quick

Contra

- Your token is easily exposed if you forget that you have your token in your file and e.g. upload it to Github

**Putting it in a JSON/toml/other seperate file**

Pro

- Still quite quick
- You can gitignore the file where you are storing the token

Contra

- You need to parse the token every time you need it
- still insecure if someone gets ahold of your file (for example if you forget to gitignore it)

**Saving your token as a system variable**

Pro

- Doesn't work from a different machine -> very hard for someone to get ahold of it
- Quite quick

Contra

- You need to be able to access system variables
- Hard to containerize

These are the main "quick and dirty" options. If you have a question about how any specific option works, you may ask here. If you want to know how to **implement a specific option**, ask another question on Stackoverflow.